# mod rewritten directory shorten

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, directory

I can only find mod rewrite examples/tutorials for query's, so can someone help me with this.

I would like this

```
http://website.tld/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/File.exten
```

to be transformed into

```
http://website.tld/Folder4/File.exten
```

Folder4 and Folder5 are multiple directories, while Folder 1-3 stay the same.
Also File.exten also should be changeable in the rewrite.
thanks.

Comment: If the user is asking only for /Folder4/File.exten, how are you going to figure out the value of Folder5?

Comment: I would gues, that the folder is always the same. If it's not, there mist be a much more complex regex to select this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/$1/Folder5/$2 [QSA,NC]
```

`([^/]+)` is better since `^(.*)/(.*)$` would match `http://website.tld/somedir/somedir2/somedir3/`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/$1/Folder5/$2 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: If "Folder5" is not always within the rewriting fil path, you can leave it out. The rewrite will then anyways be able to get you to that folder, as long as you use something like "Folder4/Folder5" in the query. Therefore I used (.*) and not ([^/]+) in my regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^grab /public/files/download/download.php
```

this rule would transform this user's URL..

http://mysite/grab?file=my.zip

server-side, into..

http://mysite/public/files/download/download.php?file=my.zip

says here: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php